# Entity select element - referencing taxonomy, displaying and submitting from fields on term

Tags: webforms

I have a form, with your normal suspects of fields... First Name, Last Name, Email, A text area.

But I want to submit data to this form that will help the CRM that receives route it to the right sales person.

This data is in a taxonomy vocab we're gonna call "Service Level"

The terms in this vocab have 3 fields.

- Name (the normal drupal field you put the term name in)
- Searchable Label
- CRM Email Address

Each term of course gets a name, and those names show up across the site as we tag things with these terms... They are mostly 3 or 4 letter acronyms that make sense elsewhere...

On this webform though, I'd like to use Entity Select to list these terms, but...
Display the "Searchable Label" in the select list, and then, the EMAIL ADDRESS is what gets submitted when the webform is "submitted".

Any guidance on how to do this is appreciated.